# Ubuntu x window system random restart

Tags: 14.04, xorg, bug-reporting

## SMH

Well, after looking closer at the syslog file, I took a closer look at the problem:

```
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox CRON[2310]: (root) CMD (pkill -KILL -u sam)
```

And noticed the CRON part. My friend and fellow programmer had added a cron to my root user to run that command every 10 minutes. He will be getting his soon is all I have to say.

---

I have been having some problems with my installation of Ubuntu 14.04 for the past month or two. The first problem I have noticed is that my network connection starts off good, then maybe after 10-15 requests, starts slowing in down until it is so slow that connections time out. Then I have to disconnect from the network (wireless connection on wlan0), reconnect and the connection is fast and good as ever, but then the same situation repeats, and it has been like this for a month or two. If anyone thinks they can help me with that we can jump into a chat or email or something.

But, my main question is something different. For the past week or two, I will be working on my desktop and then suddenly it will reboot into the login screen. It is not simply logging me out, because I have two monitors and when I boot up the login screen is on the wrong monitor, while when I simply log out my monitor settings still apply and the login screen is on the proper monitor. When I experience this random "logout", the login screen is on the wrong monitor which leads me to believe it is some sort of reboot, most likely of X because of how fast it loads up.

I am not sure what could be the problem here. I posted the issue about my network connection with this post because I thought it might be related by some off chance. Other than that I have had this setup for almost a year and never with any problems.

I really need this situation taken care of as this is my development environment. I don't do anything heavy, just back end web dev.

Hardware: HP 700 215xt

**EDIT** It just happened again, and I think I realized it is when my computer goes into sleep mode. Just as it was fading into sleep mode, I went to move my mouse to wake it and x restarted.

**Second edit** It is not just when I lock the screen, it just happened again when I was in the middle of typing.

## Log files

---

`/var/log/kern.log`

```
Sep  6 19:55:06 rapbox kernel: [24688.438610] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=14:2d:27:da:86:59:dc:9b:9c:57:b6:3b:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.4 DST=192.168.1.5 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=12240 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50547 DPT=7000 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

and a lot of these:

```
Sep  6 13:50:46 rapbox kernel: [ 2819.105490] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
Sep  6 13:50:46 rapbox kernel: [ 2819.105497] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
```

`/var/log/syslog`

```
Sep  6 13:50:19 rapbox kernel: [ 2792.059818] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
Sep  6 13:50:19 rapbox kernel: [ 2792.059823] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
Sep  6 13:50:21 rapbox kernel: [ 2794.058562] net_ratelimit: 2 callbacks suppressed
```

(at one point this was being output every second for about an hour)

And then this (source of problem?):

```
Sep  6 14:10:01 rapbox kernel: [ 3974.231437] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox CRON[2310]: (root) CMD (pkill -KILL -u sam)
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox gdm-password][3106]: GLib: Source ID 44 was not found when attempting to remove it
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox colord: device removed: xrandr-Goldstar Company Ltd-L227W-374705
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox colord: device removed: xrandr-Hewlett Packard-HP 25vx-3CM516095D
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox colord: Profile removed: icc-ef580141eb91b7ed3495371499b22bb2
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox colord: Profile removed: icc-5d070a89552033a74729877065991847
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox colord: Profile removed: icc-c04ecb0d4d1c638dca014f89902b4ebb
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox colord: Profile removed: icc-c6bb0f680e6cd8f82bc015f33a0afa69
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox gdm-simple-slave[3008]: GLib: Source ID 4 was not found when attempting to remove it
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox gdm-simple-slave[3008]: GLib-GObject: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox gdm-simple-slave[3008]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox acpid: client 3013[0:0] has disconnected
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox acpid: client connected from 2340[0:0]
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox acpid: 1 client rule loaded
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox gdm-simple-slave[2335]: Failed to give slave programs access to the display. Trying to proceed.
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox dbus[938]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Sep  6 14:10:02 rapbox dbus[938]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
```

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Not seeing any errors in the Xorg log files

`$HOME/.xsession-errors*`

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd main process ended, respawning
init: at-spi2-registryd respawning too fast, stopped
init: gnome-settings-daemon main process (4465) terminated with status 1
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: gnome-session (GNOME) main process (4471) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: The log files to read are `/var/log/{kern.log,syslog,Xorg.0.log} $HOME/.xsession-errors*`. Please DO NOT add whole blobs of unread (by you) log files to your question. Small fragments only, please.

Comment: @samrap: this is a Question & Answer site...  Please don't edit your question to add an answer, but keep it as a question and add the answer in the box "Answer"  below your question...  **;-)**